# Email Server for Bugzilla on Windows

Tags: windows, smtp, bugzilla, mail-server

I have Bugzilla 4.0 installed on my Windows machine but I haven't been able to get an email server to work. Does anyone know what the easiest way is to get the email server work?

I found NTsendmail and I have that in my perl/lib directory but I'm not entirely sure how to configure bugzilla to use it.

Is there someway I could use the gmail smtp server?

Cheers,
Steiny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Bugzilla 4.4, Gmail SMTP is supported natively, but a patch can be applied for Bugzilla 4.2 or previous versions.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Windows_Gmail

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am very happy with [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) on Windows. I'm using it on all of our public web servers to send out e-mails from my ASP.NET applications.